# .NET Application Errors when running application on Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: .net, ajax, remote-desktop

I am working on a .NET application that when run in a browser on my local machine seems to run correctly.  We need to be able to run the application in a browser while Remote Desktop connected to another machine.  When we try to do so, certain button are not working.

the button is attempting to use the following method:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnid"
PopupControlID="pnl" CancelControlID="btnClose"
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlStep1Title"
BehaviorID="mpeStep1Behavior" />
```

I ran the app in chrome and saw errors in the console (i don't see the same errors when run locally)

```
GET http://(website)/ScriptResource.axd?d=fAJd3QoJckE-KfCRKu0rXTnbHtCiSPC9wy5gn0SGQ4m9EASToqhX-yfTbp0-    JXKc0&t=11e6618b 500 (( Not implemented  ))

correctingentries.aspx:9GET http://(website)/ScriptResource.axd?d=fAJd3QoJckE-  KfCRKu0rXTnbHtCiSPC9wy5gn0SGQ4mfxWYuCx0uHvZeydfnE2L70&t=11e6618b 500 (( Not implemented  ))

correctingentries.aspx:3Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
(anonymous function)correctingentries.aspx:3
correctingentries.aspx:315Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
(anonymous function)correctingentries.aspx:315
correctingentries.aspx:1030Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
Page_ValidationActivecorrectingentries.aspx:1030
(anonymous function)
```

I am sure i am missing some setting or some install that has to occur on the remote desktop machine but have not been able to find it.  I am hoping someone else has seen the issue.

Thanks!
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review if your .NET Framework is correctly installed in your IIS and the installed version matches your application.

Sys is an object in client script created by the ASP.NET Framework.

Comment: Is there a reason we would only see the issue while running on a remote desktop session?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. If you are running in a PC with ASP.NET not registered, yes.

Another solution is to see if your remote browser are disabling JavaScript. Depending your remote PC, the browser enters in security mode.

Answer (score 1):

[This might help you](http://encosia.com/updated-your-webconfig-but-sys-is-still-undefined/)

See if this url helps you out.  The most common reason for this error is JavaScript that references the Sys namespace too early.